# Allow Site and Server acces from single computer?

Tags: apache-2.2, website, http-authentication

I have a local site that I use to run a web application for my business.  Only one or two computers need to be able to access the site.
I want to allow access to only those computers (not by IP) with the application acting like a typical web app when they try to access, and block everybody else.

I need to be able to access the site from my local network, as well as from an unspecified number of remote locations that I will not know the IP adress for in advance.  I also need the site to be allowed to access several remote sites for REST/AJAX calls.

Is there a simple (relatively) way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put it behind a firewall and allow VPN access to it. Then, just configure those computers to connect to it via VPN when they need to.